# Combine ASP.NET (or Silverlight) with SAP Webdynpro

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, webdynpro

Does anybody knows possibilities or approaches to combine **ASP.NET** with **SAP Webdynpro** (or to embed/integrate Webdynpro in a ASP.NET (or **Silverlight**) application) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Netweaver 7.02 is possible to use silverlight app INSIDE SAP webdynpro application!

Answer (score 0):

As SAP Webdynpro is meant for UI development I would guess that exposing Webservices and using ASP.Net to consume them would be your best bet.